# Vue the same component tag name will impact by other data source

Tags: vue.js

I design a CMS for content editing, and I have a template＿id list for user to select what kind of template he/she wants.

my code like below:

### CodePen

https://codepen.io/Aircon/pen/NjeMwG/

### HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <section v-for="s, index in sections">
    <h3>Section {{ index }} </h3>
    <select @change="templateChange(index)" v-model="s.selected_option">
       <option value="">-----</option>
       <option v-for="t, key in templates" :value="key">{{ key }}</option>
     </select>
    <my-component></my-component>
  </section>
</div>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
var sections = [
  {
    selected_option: ''
  },
  {
    selected_option: ''
  }
];

var templates = {
  template01: {
    html: "<p>TEMPLATE01</p>"
  },
  template02: {
    html: "<p>TEMPLATE02</p>"
  }
};

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    sections: sections,
    templates: templates
  },
  methods: {
    templateChange(index) {
      console.log("option:" + sections[index].selected_option);

      Vue.component("my-component", {
        template: templates[sections[index].selected_option].html
      });
    }
  }
});
```

### The problem is

if i have more then one section, component will be impact by others selection, how can i fix it ?

Comment: You can't change compoent template on run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a component's template within another component is going to change the definition globally and is bad practice.

You should initially register two components, one for each template:

```
Vue.component("my-component-1", { template: "<p>TEMPLATE01</p>" });
Vue.component("my-component-2", { template: "<p>TEMPLATE02</p>" });
```

Change your Vue instance's data properties to include the two component names instead of the templates:

```
data: {
  sections: sections,
  components: ['my-component-1', 'my-component-2']
},
```

Change your `v-for` to loop through the new `components` array instead:

```
<option v-for="component in components" :value="component">{{ component }}</option>
```

And, finally, change the displayed component to be a dynamic component using the `:is` directive to bind the type of component to the selected option:

```
<component :is="s.selected_option"></component>
```

[Here's a working codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmXKNm)